# VBA Custom Data Types - Defaults

Tags: vba

I would like to define a custom data type in VBA, and assign a default value to an attribute.

example:

```
Public Type Fruit
    Name as String
    Color as String
    Amount as Integer 'Default 12
End Type

Public Sub UseFruit
    Dim Banana as Fruit
    Banana.Name = "Banana"
    Banana.Color = "Yellow" 
    Debug.Print Banana.Amount
End Sub
```

I would like last line in the sub to print 12; ie. if I Dim a Fruit, the default amount is a dozen unless I specify otherwise.

How can this be accomplished? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might not be what you want (and Blackhawk's answer is a good approach), but you could instead use a simple class and set defaults in `Initialize`.

Comment: I agree with @TimWilliams a class Object would probably be the best approach

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I was trying to avoid a class object as I have to hand over the macro to people who only have pretty limited knowledge of VBA. Thanks @Blackhawk, I think I'll use a function instead to set the defaults like you recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're willing to make it a Const, the best way is to have a function generate the "default" Fruit for you.

Just to demonstrate the Const, the following is valid, though of course it cannot be altered (**this is no longer valid VBA**):

```
Public Type Fruit
    Name As String
    Color As String
    Const Amount As Integer = 12
End Type
```

Since you want a default, but it must be modifiable, I suggest using a function to generate a default Fruit:

```
Public Type Fruit
    Name As String
    Color As String
    Amount As Integer
End Type

Public Sub UseFruit()
    Dim Banana As Fruit
    Banana = getDefaultFruit
    Banana.Name = "Banana"
    Banana.Color = "Yellow"
    Debug.Print Banana.Amount 'Prints 12
End Sub

Public Function getDefaultFruit() As Fruit
    getDefaultFruit.Amount = 12 'Default 12
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know which version of VBA you are using, but Const inside of Type is not valid!

Comment: Const inside Type doesn't work and VBA debugger mentions that. If you need constants, Try enumeration instead:http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx

Comment: @ErikG I added a disclaimer. However the answer still stands since the relevant code is the second part.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the same is using a Class Module instead of Type Declaration.

> In the Class named Fruit

```
Public Name as String 
Public Color as String 
Public Amount as Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Amount = 12
end sub
```

> In the Module

```
Public Sub UseFruit()
Dim Banana as New Fruit
    Banana.Name = "Banana"
    Banana.Color = "Yellow" 
    Debug.Print Banana.Amount
End Sub
```

In a Module with many Subs and Functions or bigger VBA project, this will be more clear solution instead of using Type.